# Java Swing Desktop App Example controller or manager?

Tags: java, swing, desktop

Ok I have done alot of small java apps so im a bit lost on how I want/should do this.  I have Pharma Return program I wrote in php. I want to turn into a desktop app what is the best way to handle

```
Main Program (main.java)

Return Dept (return.java)

Sales Dept (sales.java)
```

In Android If I want to go from main to sales or sales to Returns I would call the new intent  How do I handle this within a java desktop app??

Sorry Im a learn by example guy and I have searched everywhere looking for diff methods the past week and just havent had a lightbulb come on

Thx,
Eric

Comment: This is a little vague, you are asking how to architect an application we know nothing about.

Comment: If you are asking for Java tools that can achieve want you want, I guess Java has a large library support for anything you can imagine as long as you know where to get those parts for your Java app. For GUI, you can use Swing; for database, Java has many DB connectors; etc., etc.

Comment: I was looking for some common practices. I have been reading so much it starts to become brain overload. As for the application it really was just to explain. Main Program is just a collection of separate modules I was wondering how Java Developers navigate between them and what the best practices were

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) correctly, it  is used to navigate among separate applications. On the Swing desktop, navigation is usually handled by menus, buttons, tabs, tool bars, etc. Before committing to a particular design, it might help to browse through common [Swing components](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html). Given two modules, sales and returns, [`JTabbedPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) might be a suitable choice.

Comment: Thx Trash you have it right. I have read many of your answers leading up to my question while researching.  I am going to try to make an App using Eclipse RCP

Comment: Interesting; browsing the [faq](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform#FAQs) prompts me to ask, "Swing or SWT?"